# How to capture File explorer with LoadRunner?

Tags: loadrunner, explorer, sap-gui

my problem is that I have to upload a file using SAP GUI by opening the file explorer in certain moment and SAP GUI protocol isn't able to handle with the explorer. Anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having talked with HP Support experts, the answer is really simple: is not possible to record any Windows File explorer window by using the SAPGUI protocol. It's not supported.

Comment: Current, for protocol level virtual users (i.e. Non GUI layer) you should never expect to record any actions for a common dialog, such as a file, print, etc... because it it out of context to your recording model.  If you insist on having a GUI event recorded then you need a GUi recording model, such as GUI Virtual User, Citrix or RDP

Answer (score 0):

Examine your script very, very carefully for file path which is returned from the file explorer.

Comment: I'm not able to put the path in any textbox or whatsoever. Actually, the only thing I see is a button to open the file explorer.

Comment: Common dialog boxes, such as File Open, Print, etc..., are not expected to show up in API level test code, only in GUI level test code.  As a data element to go into a field on the form, examine very carefully the recorded code for a reference to your file.  You should not ever expect to see the dialog box show up unless you're running a QTP-based GUI Virtual User, A citrix user or an RDP user.