# Loadrunner. File selection via Oracle app

Tags: oracle, loadrunner

I have an Oracle RMS to test. And have to select and upload the file via Oracle along the script by opening the file explorer and selecting the file. Oracle NCA + Web HTML protocols ain't able to handle with the explorer.

Script just show nothing about file selection. Just goes from 'Browse' button directly to 'Upload' button.

And I also cannot edit file path window as it is not editable by user.

How to handle it? Pls help!

The similar question was below, but no clear answer. 
[How to capture File explorer with LoadRunner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405453/how-to-capture-file-explorer-with-loadrunner)

Answer (score 1):

When recording a script try entering the path to the file in the edit box/text box, avoid pressing the select file button that will open the window, just press the text field and input your file path (Example: C:\file.txt) it will be correctly recorded and will replay correctly. If you already have the script you will have to remove the nca_button_press to open the select file window and add nca_edit_set("UPLOAD_FILE_NAME_0", "c:\file.txt");

First argument is button name, you have to find this name from logs file, a developer or doing a recording and press it and add some text to see it in the recorded script.  second is the file path you want to upload)

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that architecturally you must handle the windows file explorer which communicates with different protocols (Server Message Block Protocol) than does the Oracle HTTP application then you either need to hand code the SMB references or choose a different layer of the OSI model which can support driving the GUI.

if going the GUI path then you have GUI Virtual User, Citrix Virtual User, RDP Virtual User.   If going the code path, then you may have something as simple as a file reference which winds up in a post after your file selection to something s sophisticated as bringing the file into a buffer and pushing it across another protocol....